# friends request errors

Tags: javascript, facebook

I'm trying to create a iframe app with a multiple friends request. the dialog is showing but then you select the friends and submit is tell you no request sent but then the person will receive the request and when they accept it takes them to the application not the fan page. What i need is the request to redirect to the fan page not the application and also fix the no invites sent error.

http://www.facebook.com/HMetrozim?sk=app_137574463020200

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
              <a href="#" onclick="sendRequests();return false;"><img src="images/invite.jpg" width="136" height="33"></a> 
              <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 

FB.init({
    appId: 'appIDkey',
    status: true,
    cookie: true,
    xfbml: true
});

function sendRequests() {
    FB.ui({
        method: 'apprequests',
        message: 'Invite as many friends to win VIP tickets to Sting Festival!!!.',
        data: 'tracking information for the user'
    }, function(response) {
        if (response != null && response.request_ids && response.request_ids.length > 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < response.request_ids.length; i++) {
                alert("Invited: " + response.request_ids[i]);
            }
        } else {
            alert('No invitations sent');
        }
    });
}
//]]>  

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apprequests are for application requests not Fan pages.

Please read more at

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/ and
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/requests/